# Firebase + swift retrieving user data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just tried to retrieve data from firebase for my project. For example, display the facebook user name in UILabel. I store the facebook user data like this [image]

then retrieve the data using :

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/users/facebook:10207213459687665/name")

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

   self.facebookUserName.text = snapshot.value as! String

})
```

It works perfectly but it is pretty stupid by retrieving user name in a specific path because that could be different facebook user login.

I'm thinking like check the user is logged in and display their name or checking the currentUser or any smarter way to do this?
I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The way you're fetching your data from firebase is not that stupid. Actually, I would do exactly the same thing you're doing right now to fetch the user name. 

I think your problem is not about fetching user data from firebase, rather you're confused where to put your user's facebook ID when he's logged in.

Comment: Do you mean like add a userID for that use and retrieving the data by their userID? I think there should be a "smarter" way to do this.

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste your data structure from Firebase instead of a picture so we don't have to retype it. :-)

Comment: That's really not an easily expandable data structure. For example, what if you wanted to store something else about the user in their node; like their favorite food. Snapshot.value then becomes a dictionary with key:value pairs (name: Nicholas, food: pizza). See my answer for a couple of possibilities.

Comment: I am sorry for did not upload the structure. In this case, how can i have a better data structure ? Adding a user_id in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer in http://www.appcoda.com/firebase/

When we are trying to fetch the data from current user add this code below to store the uid(when creating user account)

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result ["uid"], forKey: "uid")
```

assign the variable:

```
var CURRENT_USER_REF: Firebase {
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}
```

implement code for function:

```
<reference>.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let currentUser = snapshot.value.objectForKey("username") as! String
        <--your code-->
        print("Username: \(currentUser)")
        self.currentUsername = currentUser
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
}
```

Then we could obsolete the ref in a direct path.

Answer (score 2):

There are 100 different ways to do this; here's a couple

```
users
  user_id_0
    facebook_id: facebook:10207213459687665
    name: Nicholas
  user_id_1
    facebook_id: facebook:12346578912345689
    name: Frank
```

in the above, you would query for the facebook_id you want, which will return the node and all of the child nodes (name, address, etc). The user_id_x is a Firebase auto-generated node name (guaranteed to be distinct)

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("facebook_id").queryEqualToValue("facebook:12346578912345689")
   .observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value) //prints the facebook_id and Frank
})
```

Another option is to use your same data structure and observe that node to load the data. Keep in mind that the facebook id is the KEY of the node, not the value - .value is key:value pairs.

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/users")
let thisUser = ref.childByAppendingPath("facebook:12346578912345689")

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

   //snapshot will contain all of the child nodes
   let userName = snapshot.value.objectForKey("name")
   self.facebookUserName.text = userName

})
```

If you just care about the users name, you could simplify your structure by using the facebook id as the key and the value would be the user name:

```
users    
 fb_10207213459687665: Nicholas
 fb_12346578912345689: Frank
```

and retrieve with the above observe code except you would again use the .value property as in your initial question.

In this case the .value property is a string as it's the only value (there are no child nodes as in the structure you posted, which could cause issues as it could be a series a key:value pairs which would crash)

Queries add some overhead so the observe is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question but I have a question. Now we implement this code because we know the the facebook_id which is "facebook:12345xxxxxxx". I am just wonder can we retrieve the **current user** user name.

Comment: All three examples return the current user name. Remember when a user authenticates to a Firebase app, three things happen. 1) Information about the user is returned in callbacks on the client device 2) The user information returned contains a uid (a unique ID) 3) The value of the auth variable in your app's Security and Firebase Rules becomes defined.  So once auth'd, you have a uid for the user which can then be used to get their information from your /users node.

Comment: but each user had different "facebook:123456xxxxx" right? how can it work with different user. what if i had 10+ or even more user ??

Comment: When the user authenticates, your app will receive notification of that and the firebase auth variable will be populated with that users uid. You can then query etc your /users node for their information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  To fix it, I created a variable that automatically references the user that's logged in:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let UsersRef = Firebase(url:"https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/users")
```

Then, under the @IBOutlet that you're trying to get the user data to show up in, write:

```
let LoggedInUser = UsersRef.childByAppendingPath("\(UsersRef.authData.uid)")
```

When you run the code, "UsersRef.authData.uid" is automatically replaced by the specific ID of the user currently logged in.  This should create a direct path to the database info of the logged in user without having to manually enter the user's ID in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data of a facebook user we can use the currentUser property of FirebaseAuth which returns a FIRUser which contains all the information about you user. After reading all the user data you can store it anywhere but for the sake of this example I have used UserDefaults.

```
 import Firebase
 func getUserInformation()
        {
            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
            if let user = user {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(user.displayName!, forKey: "Username")
                let uid = user.uid
                UserDefaults.standard.set(uid, forKey: "user_ID")
                let url = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(uid)/picture?type=square"
                UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "ImageData")
        }
    }
```