# Get All Items Related To Unique User With Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as a database to store requests from the `Requests` node. Looking for a way to get only the items where the `requestOwner` field is match the current user, this field is unique.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please post your Firebase Structure as text, not images. That way we don't have to re-type it and it's searchable. This is a basic query in Firebase and is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data), filtering data section as well as several other posts on stack overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase + swift retrieving user data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681055/firebase-swift-retrieving-user-data)